# Right-click Windows 7 file, choose action to upload to specific FTP folder

Tags: windows-7, ftp, context-menu

Is it possible to create a batch file or so which I can call from the context menu of a file (in Windows Explorer, on Win 7)... which will then automatically upload this file to a specific FTP server folder (username/ password provided in batch file, I suppose)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With Windows, you can create your own custom context menus.  MSDN has a very good write up on how to create your own [over here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171(v=vs.85).aspx).

What you would need to do is create an FTP batch script that can take the input (%1) and feed that to your batch script.  Hope that helps!